# Is It Fair To Charge Travel Expenses

Tags: freelancing, travel

I'm a freelancer, driving 110 miles (and back) to conduct a training session for a client. I normally charge my travel costs on (at cost) when I use public transport to conduct training/consultations.

Considering that I am driving, and using my own vehicle, is it fair/right/ethical to charge for travel outright, or should I incorporate this cost into the session fee? What would the client expect?

Comment: A good approach could be to use the official tax rates per mile. For the US that would be http://www.irs.gov/2014-Standard-Mileage-Rates-for-Business,-Medical-and-Moving-Announced

Comment: I would charge exactly the amount that is tax deductible as expenses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only your client can provide an answer regarding their expectations, but I can say that I do expect to pay reasonable expenses when working with freelance trainers within my own firm.   It's certainly an ethical and fair request in my opinion.

It's best to come to an agreement in advance.  Any reasonable organization should not be offended if you open this up as a topic of discussion or negotiation. If they refuse to pay explicit travel expenses, you can always reserve the right to adjust your fee accordingly.